# Searching for generic top-level exception handling pattern for Android

Tags: android, exception

We would like to establish a central exception handling in our Android app. I tried to use a pattern we successfully used in a `JavaFX` application before: Register a custom `UncaughtExceptionHandler` in GUI thread which displays a popup with a message provided by the exception.

We throw our custom AppException whenever the logic runs into an unsolvable situation. Means, we can exit execution of a callback (like onClickHandler) safely at any place.
Unfortunately, when doing this in Android the message is caught but the UI is dead. It just doesn't respond to further user interaction.

Any hint appreciated.